# Time complexity of a simple java piece of code

Tags: performance, loops, big-o, complexity-theory

I have the following piece of code and I know that is has a big-O complexity of `n*(log2(n))^2`, but I can't understand why the first two loops have a complexity of `log2(n)` each. Can someone explain me why is that? Thanks.

```cpp
for (int i = n; i>0; i/=2) {
   for (int j = 1; j < n; j*=2) {
       for (int k = 0; k < n; k+=2) { 
              ... // constant time number of operation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a loop here - is there an outer loop on `i` that you meant to include here?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite new to this and I probably deleted a line of code without knowing. I think it's fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop do `O(log(n))` iterations because the values of `i` are equal to `n` divided by powers-of-two numbers like `n, n/2, n/4, n/8, .., 1`. Indeed, to reach `0`, i must be divided by `2` at least `iCount=floor(log(n)+1)` times since `n < 2^iCount` and thus `n / (2^iCount) < 1`.

The second loop do `O(log(n))` iterations because the values of `j` are powers-of-two numbers like `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...` (the last possible value of `j` is `2^(floor(log(n))`).

The third loop do `O(n/2)` iterations because the values of `k` are `0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...`.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Thank you very much!